# Как создать список с заданным числом последних значений?

Tags: python, numpy, nan

В списке:

```
a = [np.nan,np.nan,8,np.nan,6,np.nan,np.nan,9,np.nan,
     np.nan,np.nan,3,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,1,np.nan]
```

Нужно выбрать последние три значения, чтобы получить новый список:

```
[9,3,1]
```

Как это правильно сделать?

Comment: У вас список или 1D Numpy вектор?

Comment: Если тупо в лоб без специальных модулей, то отфильтровать и взять срез.

Comment: @z4neo Последнее действие делается через простой срез `[-3:]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну хорошо, поверим, что не учебное задание. Как-то так можно с помощью `filter` и *среза*:

```
print(list(filter(lambda x: not np.isnan(x), a))[-3:])
```

Вывод:

```
[9, 3, 1]
```

Наверное, можно было бы как-то и без `lambda`, но я не знаю, как инвертировать условие фильтрации без неё и не прибегая к дополнительным библиотекам.

С помощью `Numpy` можно было бы ещё так:

```
a = np.array(a)
print(a[~np.isnan(a)][-3:])
```

Вывод:

```
[9. 3. 1.]
```

Но в этом случае числа превратятся в `np.float` из-за `np.nan` в массиве. Можно их и обратно преобразовать в `np.int`, если нужно.